# Switching SharePoint traffic from one server to another

Tags: sharepoint

For deployments, I want to be able to quickly move traffic from one front end to another with out adding additional hardware.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think with a load balancer. In normal state you can let the load balancer decide which front end to use. When you want to deploy to frontend 1, you can derive all traffic to frontend 2. Then when frontend 1 is deployed you can do the same for frontend 2.

Answer (score 0):

can't do it 'quickly' without a load balancer. Alternatively, and slower, would be to update the DNS for the site to point to the other web front end. 
HTH